# change ~ to arraylist in android

Tags: android, class, dynamic, arraylist

i have data in my column.
example:

```
nameclass= a.java~b.java~c.java
```

I want to change ~ to arraylist in my android application code. I want create intent with class dinamycally in my project

Comment: Do you mean you want to add these classes in an array list as String?

Comment: Have you tried `String[] classarray = nameclass.split("~");`?

Comment: @ MysticMagic : I want create intent use class dynamically